# How to improve the accuracy of an ARIMA model

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, arima

Im currently developing a simple ARIMA model to forecast a time-series data. Unfortunately my model is not providing good results.

Ive checked if the data is stationary through Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test. Came up as stationary (P< 0,05)

I used auto.arima to verify the p,d,q values, and it provided (2,1,1).
[image: Residuals]

[image]

The dataset has 201 data points and the time-series is measured monthly. I would like to forecast for the next 12 months, although Im still getting very bad accuracy results:

```
             ME     RMSE       MAE       MPE     MAPE
```

Test set 0.06804923 0.348731 0.2659965 -73.86601 140.3297

Why is my MAPE over 100? 
How can I improve such accuracy, am I missing any step to perform a successful ARIMA model?

DATASET:

structure(c(0.52, 0.36, 0.6, 0.8, 0.21, 0.42, 1.19, 0.65, 0.72, 
1.31, 3.02, 2.1, 2.25, 1.57, 1.23, 0.97, 0.61, -0.15, 0.2, 0.34, 
0.78, 0.29, 0.34, 0.52, 0.76, 0.61, 0.47, 0.37, 0.51, 0.71, 0.91, 
0.69, 0.33, 0.44, 0.69, 0.86, 0.58, 0.59, 0.61, 0.87, 0.49, -0.02, 
0.25, 0.17, 0.35, 0.75, 0.55, 0.36, 0.59, 0.41, 0.43, 0.21, 0.1, 
-0.21, 0.19, 0.05, 0.21, 0.33, 0.31, 0.48, 0.44, 0.44, 0.37, 
0.25, 0.28, 0.28, 0.24, 0.47, 0.18, 0.3, 0.38, 0.74, 0.54, 0.49, 
0.48, 0.55, 0.79, 0.74, 0.53, 0.28, 0.26, 0.45, 0.36, 0.28, 0.48, 
0.55, 0.2, 0.48, 0.47, 0.36, 0.24, 0.15, 0.24, 0.28, 0.41, 0.37, 
0.75, 0.78, 0.52, 0.57, 0.43, 0, 0.01, 0.04, 0.45, 0.75, 0.83, 
0.63, 0.83, 0.8, 0.79, 0.77, 0.47, 0.15, 0.16, 0.37, 0.53, 0.43, 
0.52, 0.5, 0.56, 0.45, 0.21, 0.64, 0.36, 0.08, 0.43, 0.41, 0.57, 
0.59, 0.6, 0.79, 0.86, 0.6, 0.47, 0.55, 0.37, 0.26, 0.03, 0.24, 
0.35, 0.57, 0.54, 0.92, 0.55, 0.69, 0.92, 0.67, 0.46, 0.4, 0.01, 
0.25, 0.57, 0.42, 0.51, 0.78, 1.24, 1.22, 1.32, 0.71, 0.74, 0.79, 
0.62, 0.22, 0.54, 0.82, 1.01, 0.96, 1.27, 0.9, 0.43, 0.61, 0.78, 
0.35, 0.52, 0.44, 0.08, 0.26, 0.18, 0.3, 0.38, 0.33, 0.25, 0.14, 
0.31, -0.23, 0.24, 0.19, 0.16, 0.42, 0.28, 0.44, 0.29, 0.32, 
0.09, 0.22, 0.4, 1.26, 0.33, -0.09, 0.48), .Tsp = c(1, 17.6666666666667, 
12), class = "ts")

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your data, by editing your question and putting the output of `dput(your_time_series)` in?

Comment: What are the MAPE and RMSE metrics for the test data set with no ARIMA model, just the sample mean?  A MAPE of 140 isn't bad by itself, only if, for example, the MAPE of the un-modeled data is, say, 141, in which case the model is not much of an improvement over an ARIMA(0,0,0) model.  After all, if you have a process with a mean of 0.001 and a mean absolute deviation of 10, you're going to have a large MAPE even if you know the true mean.

Comment: There is no improvement between an ARIMA (0,0,0) and any other p,d,q values I set.
0,0,0 - 
                  ME      RMSE       MAE      MPE     MAPE
Test set 0.003380952 0.3100996 0.2432071 99.85578 99.85578

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your 201 monthly values and examined them in an automatic mode with AUTOBOX , a time series analysis package that I helped to develop. The model developed is here [image] . The Actual,Fit and Forecast graph is here [image] and the ACF of the residuals is here [image] . The forecast plot for the next 12 periods is here.[image] .

There are a number of anomalous data points that will thwart any simple brute force attempt to examine candidate arima structure . auto.arima as it is not robust to latent anomalies (pulses,step shifts, seasonal pulses, local time trends ) and thusly over differences and over paramaterizes arima structure induced by the over differencing.

In terms of your "complaint" about the size of out-of-sample mapes , it all has to do with forecasting "small numbers" as was pointed out by @jbowman .

Finally the plot of the model residuals [image] markedly more visually acceptable than yours.

In closing .... to improve the accuracy of any model "Know the Assumptions" as A. Wald wisely reflected.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a time series with *negative* values where a MAPE would make sense.

I would very much recommend you disregard the MAPE. See [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352). Instead, concentrate on the (R)MSE.